# Neo4j unsupported Java runtime. use JDK 6. ubuntu 12.04

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-12.04, java, 32-bit

I am a new user to Neo4j usage and my OS is 32bit Ubuntu12.04. You need to start the server from Terminal by entering into the directory of Neo and then type

```
bin/neo4j start
```

which is all set and correct was until yesterday, there is some problem now and I get this

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended.
See the Neo4j manual.WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. 
Please use JDK 6.Neo4j Server already running with pid 3527
```

I am clueless to why this error occured suddenly.
When I run 
`localhost:7474`

on my browser it doesn't recognise it any more.I tried to update my version following [Install JDK6 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://yltechblog.blogspot.in/2012/10/install-jdk6-on-ubuntu-1204.html) link, but doesn't seem to work.Still gives the same error.
After checking for the version from terminal

```
    java -version
```

I recieve

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

How do make localhost:7474 work on my machine?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some licensing issues, Ubuntu does no longer ship Oracle/Sun JDKs directly, blame Oracle for that!

There is https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6 which automatically fetches Oracle/Sun JDKs, build local deb packages from them and puts them in a local apt repository.

Using `update-java-alternatives` you can set your system's default jdk.

Regarding the "open file" warning see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-linux-notes.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files.

Answer (score 3):

We are using Ubuntu 12.04 as well. We use OpenJDK 1.6.0_24.

We ran into similar problems when we initially used Neo4j. Here are the instructions to get pass those hurdles.

You need to be able to open more files.

- Edit /etc/security/limits.conf and add these two lines:

  root soft nofile 40000

  root hard nofile 40000
- Edit /etc/pam.d/su and uncomment or add the following line:

  session required pam_limits.so
- Finally check that limit was changed. You might need to reboot.

  ulimit -n

Returns 40000

Next in order to be able to use the webadmin on Ubuntu. You need to change one of the properties files inside neo4j. It works without this change on a Mac, I know.

- Edit the neo4j-server.properties file:

  > cd [neo4j installation]/conf/
  >
  > vim neo4-server.properties
- Change this line

  org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

The default is set to only listen for connections from localhost (that's why it works on a Mac). This way you can access the webadmin from anywhere. This can be a security problem though.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in neo4j about detection of running instance. By the reported pid there was some script about gnome and proxy, which after being killed (including parent lens script) let me start neo4j with OpenJDK. I guess they made it too smart.